# What loop-types exist in Angular 2?

Tags: loops, angular

What are the types of loops that exist in Angular 2?

I could only find `for` and `foreach`, but I'm having trouble to find any other ones. Is there a list somewhere?

Are there examples somewhere? That would help in understanding very strongly.

[EDIT]:
What I am essentially looking for is a list of all the different loop types in Angular 2.

[EDIT 2]:
What I really mean are the loops specific to Angular 2 within the template-section (Sorry, I didn't know there were so many possibilities). To give an example with *ngFor:

```
<ul class="contacts">
  <li *ngFor="#contact of contacts"
      (click)="onSelectContact(contact)"
      [class.selectedContact]="contact === selectedContact">
    <span class="badge">{{contact.id}}</span> {{contact.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that the `#contact` syntax no longer appears to apply and `let` is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only template loop directive in Angular 2 is [ngFor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html), and it only works with iterables, typically arrays.  (In Angular 1, `ng-repeat` would also work with objects, but Angular 2 does not.)

You can use a [pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) to format, filter, sort, etc. the list before displaying it.

Comment: Ok, this explains, why it is hard to find different sorts of loops. Thanks for your answer and for the pipe-link.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ngFor` directive in Angular 2 for looping/iterating.

Like this

`<li *ngFor="#item of items; #i = index">...</li>`

Documentation for this directive can be found here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

And an example of this being done within the Developer Guides on Angular 2's website
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html#!#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. What I am though looking for is a list of the different loop types in Angular 2.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2 is a JavaScript framework. loops for JavaScript can work in Angular 2 as well. See the below use of do while in plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/s9hfAcdjW6QU0Abj8UqQ?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2> // Output Hello Angular2 0123456789

    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 '
    this.testLoop();
  }

  testLoop(){
    var i = 0;
    do {
       this.name += i;
       i++;
    }
    while (i < 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your post. I really meant the loops inside of the `template` within the component definition. Even though thanks for providing another way. You never learn out. ;)

Comment: Angular 2 is not a JS framework, it is a web framework compatible with JS, TS and Dart.

Answer (score 0):

For live [output click...](http://embed.plnkr.co/5btVMZ/preview)

Example,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ng for loop in angular 2 with ES5.</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.sfx.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
        var ngForLoop = function () {
            this.msg = "ng for loop in angular 2 with ES5.";
            this.users = ["Anil Singh", "Sunil Singh", "Sushil Singh", "Aradhya", 'Reena'];
        };

        ngForLoop.annotations = [
                new angular.Component({
                    selector: 'ngforloop'
                }),
                new angular.View({
                    template: '<H1>{{msg}}</H1>' +
                            '<p> User List : </p>' +
                            '<ul>' +
                            '<li *ng-for="#user of users">' +
                            '{{user}}' +
                            '</li>' +
                            '</ul>',
                    directives: [angular.NgFor]
                })
        ];

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            angular.bootstrap(ngForLoop);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ngforloop></ngforloop>
    <h2>
      <a href="http://www.code-sample.com/" target="_blank">For more detail...</a>
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```